# How to use more than one related dataset?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I've got several related json data files. Without giving too much away about the proprietary data, and to make it simple ...

Say one json file `"businesses"` describes businesses, with features being their name, address, etc, and a unique ID. This numbers in the hundreds of thousands.

Then another json file `"ratings"` holds the ratings 1-5 for businesses those given by customers, keyed by unique customer ID and the business ID. All the ratings correspond to businesses in `"businesses"` (I hope). `"ratings"` is a much smaller file and in fact I am using just 1000 of the tens of thousands of ratings I have.

I have some other related files but I'll just limit it to these for now.

Say I make some kind of d3 chart of the ratings, like a bar chart where each vertical bar represents one business and the height is determined by their avg rating.

I want to make it so that when you hover over a bar you can see the business name, for example, and to do that I have to draw from both `"businesses"` and `"ratings"`. I've only seen examples with one dataset throughout.

I load two datasets and assigning each to a variable:

(Usually I error-check but I'm removing that for simplicity)

```
var businesses = [];
var ratings = [];
d3.json("data/business.json", function(json) {
    businesses = json;
    console.log(businesses);
}); 
d3.json("data/rating.json", function(json) {                
    ratings = json;
    console.log(ratings);
});
```

Both data sets appear in the console. I make the bars, something like this:

```
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);
svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(ratings)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    (more attribs for ht, width, fill, etc.)
```

I can show the business id:

```
.append("title").text(function(d) {return "" + d.business_id ;});
```

but it is just a meaningless string of characters, numbers, hyphens, and underscores.

How might I most efficiently pluck the business name that matches that ID from the businesses array?

---

I tried

```
.append("title").text(function(d) {return getBizName(d.business_id); });
```

which calls

```
var getBizName = function(bizId) {
    var i;
    for (i=0; i<businesses.length; i++) {
        if (businesses[i].business_id==bizId) return businesses[i].name;
    }
};
```

It doesn't work. I've tried a few approaches and if I get titles to appear at all, they say `undefined`. If I type `getBizName(some-valid-business-id)` in the console, it says `some-valid-business-id is not defined`.

Any ideas? Keep in mind I am new at this so I make a lot of dumb mistakes. I'm also sleepy. Thanks.

Comment: This was asked yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26128426/d3-how-to-dynamically-refresh-a-graph-by-changing-the-data-file-source/

Comment: I don't see how that would work for this. I'm not using a second file that has the same type of data in it.

Comment: Also the user shouldn't have to click anything to see the titles.

Comment: It's simple: you'd tailor the variables, similar to how you'd tailor the data file, for your chart update function. You'd change your event trigger.

Comment: I tried removing the event altogether and just doing updateChart(data1); updateChart(data2); but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't know the structure of your `businesses` and `ratings` array, I'm not sure what's wrong with your `getBizName` function, but generally, that technique would work fine.

See example here (hovering over bars shows business name): http://jsfiddle.net/n1qnyv9u/

If `name` is somewhere else deeper inside the `businesses` array, you may be accessing it incorrectly.

**Edit:** Since you say that `businesses` is usually a large dataset and `ratings` is much smaller, you may want to use `array.map` to update `ratings` to include `name` ahead of time. That way, you won't have to call `getBizName` every time a `ratings` bar is hovered over.

After you get the data in `businesses` and `ratings`, do this:

```
ratings.map(function(a) {
    a.business_name=getBizName(a.bid);
    return a;
  }
);
```

Now `ratings` includes `business_name`. When constructing the title element, just use the `business_name` like below:

```
.append("title").text(function(d) { return d.business_name; });
```

Updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/n1qnyv9u/2/

You may also want to look at https://github.com/Caged/d3-tip for better-looking tooltips.

Comment: I adjusted the code and it still produces strange errors that I'm trying to get to the bottom of but thanks for that.

Comment: Got it working with my huge datasets, very excited. Thanks so much!