# D3 Realtime Line Chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new to D3 and I'd like to know how to update a chart when the data changes. Here's the code for my chart:

```
var data = [
  { time: new Date(2017, 3, 8, 20, 0, 0), value: 30 },
  { time: new Date(2017, 3, 8, 20, 15, 0), value: 25 },
  { time: new Date(2017, 3, 8, 20, 30, 0), value: 35 },
  { time: new Date(2017, 3, 8, 20, 45, 0), value: 15 },
  { time: new Date(2017, 3, 8, 21, 0, 0), value: 20 }
];

var margin = { top: 20, left: 50, bottom: 20, right: 20 };
var height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right;

var svg = d3.select("#chart").attr("width","100%").attr("height","100%");

var group = svg.append("g")
                    .attr("height", height)
                    .attr("width", width)
                    .attr("transform","translate("+margin.left+","+margin.top+")");

var x = d3.scaleTime()
          .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d){return d.time;}))
          .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
          .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d){return d.value;}))
          .range([height, 0]);

var points = group.append("g").attr("class", "points");

var line = d3.line()
              .x(function(d){ return x(d.time); })
              .y(function(d){ return y(d.value); });

// graph points
points.append("path")
          .attr("fill", "none")
          .attr("stroke", "blue")
          .attr("strok-width", "3")
          .attr("d", line(data));

// add x axis
group.append("g")
      .attr("class","axis x")
      .attr("transform","translate(0, "+height+")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

// add y axis
group.append("g")
      .attr("class","axis y")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

// y axis label
group.append("text")
      .attr("transform","rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 0 - margin.left/1.5)
      .attr("x",0 - (height / 2))
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text("value");

// x axis label
group.append("text")
      .attr("transform","translate("+width/2+","+(height+margin.top+margin.bottom)+")")
      .style("text-anchor", "center")
      .text("time");
```

How do I make it so that when new data is updated, eg. `data.push({ time: new Date(2017, 3, 8, 21, 15, 0), value: 28 })` the chart updates to reflect the new data? I've seen some examples such as ones [here](http://bl.ocks.org/charlesdguthrie/11356441) and [here](http://bl.ocks.org/simenbrekken/6634070) but it's not very clear how the update part works. A little explanation in your answer would be nice as well, just enough for me to understand :)

Comment: is this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26128426/d3-how-to-dynamically-refresh-a-graph-by-changing-the-data-file-source

Comment: looks like it's just creating the chart each time, is that the recommended way of making a chart realtime? Seems a little inefficient especially if there are multiple updates per second.